# How to remove all references to a library?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I have a pretty classical error during my project building:

```
ld: library not found for -lAppLovinSdk
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Originally I got the library from Cocoapods pod, but then I started having a lot of errors and decided to remove the pod from the Podfile and executed `pod update`

My Podfile looks like this:
[image]

I've tried to clean project, reinstall the Podfile, deleting `Pods` folder and `Podfile.lock` file, `"Build Active Architecture Only"` is set to `"No"`, but I still have the error. I assume I still have some references to libraries from the deleted Pod. What is the way to get rid of them?

**UPDATE**: Here is a full error message:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I figured out the problem:

I had to go to `Target -> Build Settings -> Linking -> Other Linking Flags` and there I had to remove all deleted libraries references, manually. And then it worked!